# Move method from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

To the suggestion of several people I have been told to keep my controller as concise as possible.  Currently I have this in my controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raw_result = params[:search] ||= "man on fire"
    result = raw_result.gsub(/\s+/, "+")
    movie_details = HTTParty.get("http://imdbapi.org/?title="+result+"&type=json")
    @searches = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(movie_details)
  end
end
```

How do I turn it into a new class in my model and call back to it again in the controller?

Current model and controller:

```
class IMDBSearcher
  def self.search(search)
    raw_result = search || "man on fire"
    result = raw_result.gsub(/\s+/, "+")
    movie_details = HTTParty.get("http://imdbapi.org/?title="+result+"&type=json")

    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(movie_details)      
  end
end

class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @searches = IMDBSearcher.search(params[:search]) 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an instance method you call it like this:

```
instance.search(something)
```

If it is a class method you call it like:

```
IMDBSearcher.search(something)
```

BUT, to do this you have to create your method like this:

```
def self.search(raw_result)
```

The trick here is the use of the `self` keyword, transforming the method in a class method (because self here is the class IMDBSearcher). For example:

```
def self.search(search)
  raw_result = search || "man on fire"
  result = raw_result.gsub(/\s+/, "+")
  movie_details = HTTParty.get("http://imdbapi.org/?title="+result+"&type=json")

  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(movie_details)      
end
```

And in the controller you do something like:

```
@searches = IMDBSearcher.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: i get an error in the view: uninitialized constant SearchesController::IMDBSearcher

Comment: Strange, `IMDBSearcher` is a model in your app, no? Could you post your controller and model code?

Comment: I updated the question with my current model and controller.  double checked spelling not sure why i get that error

Comment: I really don't know why your model is not being recognized, i'm thinking about it. The code is in github?

Comment: Yes it is here [https://github.com/emailnitram/movies/tree/test](https://github.com/emailnitram/movies/tree/test)

Comment: Ok, i will clone it and see if and can figure it out. :)

Comment: @emailnitram I just sent you a pull request. Problem solved. :)